# Visual Studio 2012 - Web Test Recorder bar issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, performance-testing, internet-explorer-10

When I try to record a Web Performance Test in Visual Studio 2012, the web test recorder bar doesn't display in Internet Explorer 10.

When I sign into my pc with a different user, I can see two IE add-ons:

- Microsoft Web Test Recorder 10.0 Helper
- Web Performance Test 10.0

and I see the web test recorder bar correctly.

But with my user, there isn't the "Web Performance Test 10.0" add-on. So when I start to record a new Web Performance Test, a new web browser opens up but the browser doesn’t have the recorder bar.

I've looked into all of [these suggestions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mtaute/archive/2007/11/09/diagnosing-and-fixing-web-test-recorder-bar-issues.aspx) and unfortunately haven't had any luck resolving the problem.

I'm running Windows 8 x64, Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 with Update 1 (11.0.51106.01) and Internet Explorer 10 (10.0.9200.16484).